# My video keeps automatically switching to 600 fps?

Tags: video

I am attempting to cut out exactly 30 frames of a video at 30 fps to string together with other 1 second videos.  I had no problem doing this with a previous version of Blender.

Now for some reason in Blender v2.8, every time I do so by setting my render frame start and end to the 30 frames I want (let's say 71-100), when I render it and then bring that file back into blender, the audio strip will correctly be 1 second (30 frames), but the video strip will be 581 frames.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a better question would be: What is the best way to import a video, set it to 30 fps, cut out 30 frames, and export it as a new file, a 1 second, 30 frame video with audio.  FYI I have been using 1920x1080p, FFmpeg video, AVI container, MPEG-4 video codec, and mp3 audio codec.  All similar to what I was doing on an older version of blender without problems